# IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate with Play Framework 2.6.7 Java imports 'symbol not resolved'

Tags: intellij-idea, playframework, playframework-2.0

Be it an example project, freshly downloaded from Play Framework's website, or my project which is derived from that with a few changes to templates - nothing big - IntelliJ just can't seem to find the appropriate dependencies or sources necessary for Play development.

I've already installed Scala plugin for IntelliJ, which includes support for Play Framework. I'll outline the process that I've followed, after reading multiple articles from Play's documentation as well as questions asked on here though no answer has proven incredibly useful as yet.

1. Open Project Settings within IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2017.2.6
2. Click `Modules` > `[+]` > `Import Module`
3. Find build.sbt within project root
4. Import with default SBT settings:

   - Download: `[checked]` Library sources, `[checked]` SBT source
   - `[unchecked]` Use SBT shell for build and import (requires sbt 0.13.5+)
   - Project JDK: `[9.0 (java version 9.0.1)]` -- Could this be the problem? (compatibility)

SBT compiles and I get this error, which I somewhat dismissed but reading it now seems to be somewhat telltale but I am unsure of what: https://pastebin.com/tXbHQdek

Running the site works, using `sbt run`, but when opening `.java` sources, IntelliJ marks errors upon `import play.mvc.*` though `import views.html.*` works fine. Adding framework support for `Play 2.x` seems to do next to nothing, as no project settings seem to change, and the error is not resolved.

This behavior exists with a clean IntelliJ 2017 Ultimate install (as of today) and an example project from Play Framework with no modifications, so if a solution cannot be found I'll probably consider posting an issue on one or more of their issue trackers.

Any ideas on how to get my Play Framework development environment working?
Thanks :3

Comment: Most warnings / errors in that pastebin can be safely ignored, that is just IntelliJ not finding certain source / javadoc files, which is to be expected as not everyone publishes those. However, the one at the top that says it can't bind to a port because its already taken might be problematic. See if you have any other instances of sbt running, and stop those. Another place you can check is the Project Structure dialog, it has a problems tab that can give some useful information sometimes.

Comment: The cause indeed most likely is `[error] server failed to start on 127.0.0.1:4214. java.net.BindException: Address already in use: NET_Bind` Can you build by sbt from command line? Can you ping the 127.0.0.1 ip address? Check the loopback interface is configured and can accept the tcp connections. Also check av/firewall - that it does not block IDE when it tries to connect to the specified port on localhost.

Comment: No antivirus or firewall, because I am a smart human being. Also, running a netstat shows no activity on port 4214. I'm downgrading to Java 8 after reading some stuff in the Google group for Play Framework, will report back if I find anything interesting.

Answer (score 0):

This did not originally occur to me but in my search through the Play Framework Google group, I found a suggestion on a somewhat recent post to uninstall Java 9 as Play's dependencies are not yet compatible with it and hence won't resolve.

For anyone who might come across this issue, hopefully this saves you some days headbanging:

1. Optional - Uninstall JDK and JRE 9
2. Install JDK 8 (comes with JRE)
3. From within IntelliJ, `File` > `Project Structure` > `SDKs` > [any Java 9 JDK] > `[-]`
4. `[+]` > `Find your JDK 8 installation folder

   - 32 bit: `C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk****/`
   - 64 bit: `C:/Program Files/Java/jdk****/`
   - Where `****` is your Java version, such as `1.8_152`, as in `jdk1.8_152`
5. Press OK. You'll get a warning that the project SDK is missing or similar, so click the link it provides you to configure that and select your newly configured JDK.

Everything should work from there, just straight away after IntelliJ indexes, which can be tracked in the bottom right corner as with all other operation progress.